# iOS: Destination point given distance and bearing from start point

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, geolocation

Given a start point, initial bearing, and distance, this will calculate the destination point and final bearing travelling along a (shortest distance) great circle arc:

```
var lat2 = 

Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) +                       
Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );

var lon2 = 

lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1),  
       Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
```

This code is in JavaScript.
I'dd like the same thing for iOS, so in objective-c.

Anyone knows about a class that would do the trick?

Comment: There are some great books on C and objective-c in the amazon book store. I suggest buying one and learning the language. besides from that take a look at math.h

Answer (score 4):

I'm not translating your Javascript, this is just a routine I found somewhere for a project of mine that does the same thing:

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) NewLocationFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)startingPoint 
                         atDistanceInMiles:(float)distanceInMiles 
                     alongBearingInDegrees:(double)bearingInDegrees {

    double lat1 = DEG2RAD(startingPoint.latitude);
    double lon1 = DEG2RAD(startingPoint.longitude);

    double a = 6378137, b = 6356752.3142, f = 1/298.257223563;  // WGS-84 ellipsiod
    double s = distanceInMiles * 1.61 * 1000;  // Convert to meters
    double alpha1 = DEG2RAD(bearingInDegrees);
    double sinAlpha1 = sin(alpha1);
    double cosAlpha1 = cos(alpha1);

    double tanU1 = (1 - f) * tan(lat1);
    double cosU1 = 1 / sqrt((1 + tanU1 * tanU1));
    double sinU1 = tanU1 * cosU1;
    double sigma1 = atan2(tanU1, cosAlpha1);
    double sinAlpha = cosU1 * sinAlpha1;
    double cosSqAlpha = 1 - sinAlpha * sinAlpha;
    double uSq = cosSqAlpha * (a * a - b * b) / (b * b);
    double A = 1 + uSq / 16384 * (4096 + uSq * (-768 + uSq * (320 - 175 * uSq)));
    double B = uSq / 1024 * (256 + uSq * (-128 + uSq * (74 - 47 * uSq)));

    double sigma = s / (b * A);
    double sigmaP = 2 * kPi;

    double cos2SigmaM;
    double sinSigma;
    double cosSigma;

    while (abs(sigma - sigmaP) > 1e-12) {
        cos2SigmaM = cos(2 * sigma1 + sigma);
        sinSigma = sin(sigma);
        cosSigma = cos(sigma);
        double deltaSigma = B * sinSigma * (cos2SigmaM + B / 4 * (cosSigma * (-1 + 2 * cos2SigmaM * cos2SigmaM) - B / 6 * cos2SigmaM * (-3 + 4 * sinSigma * sinSigma) * (-3 + 4 * cos2SigmaM * cos2SigmaM)));
        sigmaP = sigma;
        sigma = s / (b * A) + deltaSigma;
    }

    double tmp = sinU1 * sinSigma - cosU1 * cosSigma * cosAlpha1;
    double lat2 = atan2(sinU1 * cosSigma + cosU1 * sinSigma * cosAlpha1, (1 - f) * sqrt(sinAlpha * sinAlpha + tmp * tmp));
    double lambda = atan2(sinSigma * sinAlpha1, cosU1 * cosSigma - sinU1 * sinSigma * cosAlpha1);
    double C = f / 16 * cosSqAlpha * (4 + f * (4 - 3 * cosSqAlpha));
    double L = lambda - (1 - C) * f * sinAlpha * (sigma + C * sinSigma * (cos2SigmaM + C * cosSigma * (-1 + 2 * cos2SigmaM * cos2SigmaM)));

    double lon2 = lon1 + L;

    // Create a new CLLocationCoordinate2D for this point
    CLLocationCoordinate2D edgePoint = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(RAD2DEG(lat2), RAD2DEG(lon2));

    return edgePoint;
}
```

Comment: the calculations in this answer are more complex than the formula given in the OP, but they do seem to work.  Any idea if theres a writeup somewhere about the logic behind this function?

Comment: @D-Nice I had saved a handful of useful websites I'd used to finalize this, including one that provided it in pseudocode and explained much of how it worked, but unfortunately it appears I've deleted them. If I track them down I'll post them, but odds aren't great (retrieving them from a backup is a bit more work than I can put into an answer right now).

Comment: This calculation is the Vincenty formula, which will be more accurate than the Haversine formula from the OP.  The Vincenty formula is accurate down to 0.5 mm (which is pretty crazy), and the Haversine is less accurate but quicker. But, seeing as how you aren't doing it by hand, might as well go with Vincenty.[link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae

Comment: Most well deserved upvote I have given until now. Well done sir, well done !

Answer (score 0):

You are making things very difficult :)

Just try my code:

```
LatDistance = Cos(BearingInDegrees)*distance;
LongDistance = Sin(BearingInDegrees)*distance;

CLLocationDegrees *destinationLat = CurrentLatitude + (LatDistance*0.00001);
CLLocationDegrees *destinationLong = CurrentLongitude + (LongDistance*0.00001);
```

That's it. Very simple.